# API Gateway REST API integration request path rewriting with multiple path parts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway REST API with an integration to S3. We don't want to directly expose the buckets and object keys so there is an authorizer that is taking a path parameter and returning an object key. This object key may contain a number of path parameters, eg, `path/to/object`. I want to be able to rewrite the integration path to include this.

When I try using a path variable the value is replaced but it's URL encoded, ie, `path%2Fto%2Fobject` so of course the S3 request fails. I don't see any way of replacing the path variable with a value that contains multiple path parameters. I've also tried the same thing using `#context.requestOverride.path.XXX` in a mapping template and it also ends up URL encoded. I've tried using `$utils.urlDecode()` but again the result is encoded.

Is there any way to replace a path variable with multiple path segments? Otherwise, is there a way to completely replace the path in a mapping template (not just specific path variables)? Or is there another way to achieve this eg can the object key be passed in a header?

Comment: I'm also having a similar question to re-write url path at API Gateway for a websocket api and http integration. Did you find anything?

Comment: @diegosasw I never solved the multiple path part problem. I ended up settling on a bucket convention so that there were a known number of path parts and replaced them individually.